# Unable to send image attachment to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to send the image data along with other input fields but was successfully able to send the other info but not the image. Please help me with the following code I have to send an image attachment from React frontend.

**CompanyForm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function CompanyForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [upload, setUpload] = useState(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const AddInfo = async () => {
    let formField = new FormData()

    formField.append('name', name)
    formField.append('title', title)
    formField.append('price', price)
    formField.append('upload', upload)

    if (upload !== null) {
      formField.append('upload', upload)
    }


    const AddInfo = () => {
      const formField = new FormData()
      formField.append('name', name)
      formField.append('title', title)
      formField.append('price', price)
      formField.append('upload', upload)

    }

    await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/',
      data: formField,

      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },

    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
      navigate('/')
    })

  }


  return (
    <form>
      <div className="mb-3">

        <label for="Name" className="form-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      </div>

      <div className="mb-3">
        <label for="title" className="form-label">Title</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="title" value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label for="price" className="form-label">Price</label>
        <input type="number" className="form-control" name="price" value={price} onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="upload" class="form-label">Upload</label>

        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="upload" onChange={(e) => setUpload(e.target.files[0])} />
      </div>

      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={AddInfo}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default CompanyForm;
```

Also, other data in the form is successfully forwarded to backend but image field going blank means without image

Comment: We need info about the BACK-END too. The controller, what type of data is it expecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `headers` value

From `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` to

```
headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
```

Full change can be

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function CompanyForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [upload, setUpload] = useState(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const AddInfo = async () => {
    let formField = new FormData()

    formField.append('name', name)
    formField.append('title', title)
    formField.append('price', price)
    formField.append('upload', upload)

    if (upload !== null) {
      formField.append('upload', upload)
    }


    const AddInfo = () => {
      const formField = new FormData()
      formField.append('name', name)
      formField.append('title', title)
      formField.append('price', price)
      formField.append('upload', upload)

    }

    await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/',
      data: formField,

      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },

    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
      navigate('/')
    })

  }


  return (
    <form>
      <div className="mb-3">

        <label for="Name" className="form-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      </div>

      <div className="mb-3">
        <label for="title" className="form-label">Title</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="title" value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label for="price" className="form-label">Price</label>
        <input type="number" className="form-control" name="price" value={price} onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="upload" class="form-label">Upload</label>

        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="upload" onChange={(e) => setUpload(e.target.files[0])} />
      </div>

      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={AddInfo}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default CompanyForm;
```

Comment: Done that still don't work: 
await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/',
      data: formField,

      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
     }

    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
      navigate('/')
    })

  }

Comment: What did you get in the back-end logs? @AMRITSHAHI

Comment: please see: 'upload': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: logo.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: logo.png (image/png)>]}>):

Comment: Complete Details:

DataSearilizers(data=<QueryDict: {'name': ['ssssssssssssssss'], 'title': ['ssssssssssss'], 'price': ['444444444444'], 'upload': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: logo.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: logo.png (image/png)>]}>):
    name = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=30, required=False)
    title = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=30, required=False)
    price = IntegerField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    image = ImageField(allow_null=True, max_length=100, required=False)

Comment: Hmm That's weird. According to your logs, I can see that image is already sent to back-end. @AMRITSHAHI

Comment: by the way Nick thanks. It is issue due to upload has mention but used image in models.py

Answer (score 1):

```
class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "data", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

same image field should used everywhere:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" onChange={(e) => setUpload(e.target.files[0])} />
```

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question, or if it is, it is not explained well. Please [edit] either the answer to explain how it answers the question, or the question to include this if it is more information about the question.